# Perl cannot stat $_

Tags: perl

I want the last modified time for each file in the directory. To make sure my loop is working I print $_ and I see the file names of the directory:

```
for ( @Files ) {

    opendir( D, $path . '\/' . $_ ) or die "$!";
    my @textfiles = grep { ! /^\.{1,2}$/ } readdir( D );

    for ( @textfiles ) {

        #    print "$_\n";   <----the file names.
        my $epoch_timestamp = ( stat( $_ ) )[9];
        print "$epoch_timestamp\n";
    }
```

I get this error

> Use of uninitialized value $epoch_timestamp in concatenation (.) or string

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would normally recommend using `glob` instead of `readdir` as it returns the full path to the file and lets you do shellglob matching, rather than regex with `grep`. Which in _many_ cases is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readdir` returns only the names of the files. If your current working directory is different then you must build the full path as you did with the parameter to `opendir`. The easiest way is to use `map` in the list for the `for` loop

I'm concerned about your statement

```
opendir( D, $path . '\/' . $_ ) or die "$!";
```

which will put, literally, `\/` between `$path` and `$_`. I think you need just `/`, but it is simplest to *interpolate* the variables with

```
opendir( D, "$path/$_" ) or die "$!";
```

But `$_` comes from the array `@Files`. If these are indeed file names then your `opendir` will fail. They need to be directory names

In my solution I've built the variable `$dir` as

```
my $dir = "$path/$_"
```

so that it can be used in the call to `opendir` as well as to build the full path to the files in the following `for` loop

Note that I have also used a lexical directory handle `my $dh`, which are far superior to global handles `D`

```
for ( @Files ) {

    my $dir = "$path/$_";

    opendir my $dh, $dir or die $!;
    my @textfiles = grep { ! /^\.{1,2}$/ } readdir $dh;

    for ( map { "$dir/$_" } @textfiles ) {

        #    print "$_\n";   <----the file names.
        my $epoch_timestamp = ( stat( $_ ) )[9];

        print "$epoch_timestamp\n";
    }
```

Comment: so my $_ is in this format:
\\client\Z\folder\folder2\file.txt

I successfully built the full path to then do the stat command on the variable. I still get the "use of initialized value on $epoch_timestamp".

Comment: Ok got it to work. For some reason this works: my $f=stat($filepath)->mtime; but this does not work: my $epoch_timestamp = ( stat( $_ ) )[9];

Answer (score 2):

Or alternatively to above perfect answers, you could use some modules and make your life more easy. :) Like: [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)<sup>[1]</sup>

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;

my $path = path('/etc');
my @Files = qw(defaults cups ssl);

for my $dir (@Files) {
    my @textfiles = $path->child($dir)->children;
    for my $file (@textfiles) {
        say "$file: ", $file->stat->mtime;
    }
}
```

Of course, the above the nested loop could be written as

```
for my $dir (@Files) {
    my @textfiles = $path->child($dir)->children;
    say "$_: ", $_->stat->mtime for (@textfiles);
}
```

and also storing the list of files into `@textfiles` isn't necessary, so it could be reduced to:

```
for my $dir (@Files) {
    say "$_: ", $_->stat->mtime for ( $path->child($dir)->children );
}
```

---

1. Path::Tiny conveniently throws a clean exception message on error.

Answer (score 0):

`readdir` only returns the name of the file in the directory. You need to provide a qualified path to the file to `stat`.

```
my $dir_qfn = ...;
opendir(my $dh, $dir_qfn)
    or do {
        warn("Can't read dir \"$dir_qfn\": $!\n");
        next;
    };

while (defined( my $fn = readdir($dh) )) {
   next if $fn =~ /^\.\.?\z/;

   my $qfn = "$dir_qfn/$fn";
   my $mtime = ( stat($qfn) )[9];
   defined($mtime)
       or do {
           warn("Can't stat file \"$file_qfn\": $!\n");
           next;
       };

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `glob` instead

```
my $dir = ...;

my %ts =
    map { $_ => (stat $_)[9] }
        grep { !m{/\.\.?\z} }    #/
            glob "\Q$dir\E/{*,.*}";

say "ts{$_} => $_" for sort keys %ts;
```

I use a hash *name => timestamp* to collect both in a data structure.  The pattern `$dir/{*,.*}` is there to catch dot files as well, or it would be just `$dir/*`.

The `grep` filters out `.` and `..` filenames, found in path by `m{..}` match. Its pattern needs `\Q..\E` to prevent an injection bug with particular directory names.  It also escapes spaces so `File::Glob` with its `:bsd_glob`option isn't needed. Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for comments.

If you'd rather process files one at a time, retrieve the list with `glob` and then iterate through it.

Comment: @ikegami Ah, right, you told me that already! Will adjust. Thank you, and for edits.  I "in-lined" filtering to not  pass over the list twice but that's non-sense as this is so much cleaner and probably not slower at all (with an `if` branch in that souped up `map`), except for extremely long lists.

Comment: This is IO-driven. The extra sub calls (which are actually lighter-than-normal "multi-calls") that are incurred from using `grep`+`map` instead of just `map` are not gonna make a difference, and well worth the extra readability (especially in a SO answer).